# NodeJS + Socket.io SSL fails after a few connections

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io

I'm running NodeJS with socket.io, all under SSL.  I've recently moved servers and what used to work fine now stops working after a couple of minutes - Chrome says the connection is reset, and curl says there are SSL problems.

I've tried with and without express - neither with any success after a couple of minutes.

So - my minimal code is:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

const options = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('XXX.key'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('XXX.crt'),
    ca:     fs.readFileSync('XXX.ca')
};

var app = https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('(not imporant)\n');
}).listen(3000);

var io = require('socket.io')(app);
```

If I comment out the last line, the server always accepts new connections (albeit without socket.io) and everything works.  If I leave that last line in, it works for a minute, various SSL checking tools are all ok, including:

```
openssl s_client -connect REDACTED.com:3000
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 /C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Hosted by XILO Communications Ltd./OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.REDACTED.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
 3 s:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
REDACTED
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Hosted by XILO Communications Ltd./OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.REDACTED.com
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5650 bytes and written 456 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 704A23D4B00B3A445A8C9097427FF26B724458F24B105C847B76E576FCA9C803
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 04FB6B5B06954516A073C65A456010C819B157A20F5F308EDCC88C8B0FDCD9A990D3A23AC117714363A92EB56BC98272
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1474318665
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

But shortly after (and probably a few hundred client connections from people using the site), the same command gives (from a Mac):

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
65931:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.60.1/src/ssl/s23_lib.c:185:
```

And from linux/vagrant:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140236360926880:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 295 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

curl https://REDACTED:3000 gives:

```
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to REDACTED:3000
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to overcome this?  The code works fine on our development machines, but as soon as it goes onto the live servers, it breaks pretty quickly.

Is it anything to do with the fact I'm using a wildcard certificate?

Thanks in advance.
Ed